# Export NetLogo output in .tiff or .jpg

Tags: netlogo

I have a 300x300 world and I would like to save the generated result in .jpg or tiff format. Could someone tell me if it is possible to do this? I have so far only been able to export in .txt or .csv. Sorry for the beginner's question. If anyone can provide me with some direction, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `export-view view.png` or `export-interface interface.png` in the code. Afterwards you can convert the .png to .jpg, if that's neccesairy.
If you want to do it manually, you can right click on the view and choose "Export View..." or in the upper left "File" -> "Export" -> "Export View ..."

Answer (score 1):

See post von user Lena.

In the command-center-console (near `observer>`) you can type `user-directory` to find the output-directory where Netlogo will save the file to,

and then, again in the command-center-console, type
`export-view  "myworld-view.png"`

Attempting to save as JPEG with `myworld-view.jpg`, or to save as TIFF with `myworld-view.tiff`, do *not* seem to work. These do not throw an error, but the images saved are still PNG files. (at least on  my machine).